# Why different Bluetooth OBD2 v 1.5 adapters (All made in China, they don't have a brand or model) give different responses to the same commands?

Tags: obd-ii, bluetooth

After initializing them (ATZ, ATSP0; ATE0 etc etc ) , I guess correctly, the following happens:
If, for instance,  we send the command 03 some adapters respond
4300... which is correct.
While other adapters respond with:
4300
4300
Another example
With the engine off, the response to command 010C (RPM request) is, as expected,
NO DATA
With some adapters the incorrect answer is, for example,
410476
Does anyone have an answer to this problem or can you recommend any adapter that always gives the correct answers?
Thank you so much.

Comment: An apology for the error... where it says 410476 it should say 410C7654. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sending broadcast requests (e.g. to 0x7DF)? If so, you may pick up the responses from more than one ECU.